# Sqoop command refers an incorrect DERBY schema

Tags: hive, sqoop

I have installed HIVE 2.1 and have Derby as the metastore.
Here, all the tables in DERBY are created under the schema called APP.
When I am importing data from My-Sql to HIVE via SQOOP command, the schema which is referred by SQOOP is "catalog" rather than "APP".

Can someone please help me so that the SQOOP command refers APP schema.

Comment: In a "real" Hadoop cluster, there would be a global Metastore service, and the clients would not have to care about the back-end DB. But in your case it looks like you have a minimal setup, with no global Metastore service => each Metastore client (Hive, Sqoop, Spark, Pig) must run an embedded Metastore service and connect separately to the DB. Hence all clients must find the same `hive-site.xml` in their CLASSPATH, with the same Derby URL complete with schema name.

Comment: Yes, I have the simpler setup in my laptop. But when sqoop contacts hive, I expect the same DB(in my case APP) is referred. That's why I am puzzled.